How to implement separate databases for each user in a CRUD web app?
I am currently building a simple crud web app for companies (user) to store their employee details. The problem is about "how do I implement so that each user can would have their own database with their respective employees' data?"
Note: So far I have developed the mvp and stored the data in the browser's localStorage as I am unsure of the backend integration.
From what I've found is that I can create a user database containing their id, and assigned company database id. So, upon login in, it matches the user with their own database. This is what I thought might work:
**users_table**
id
email
password
company_table_id


**companies_table**
id
user_id

Questions in mind:-

What type of database is suitable in my case?
How do I structure my database or backend to incorporate this logic?
How do I transition from saving my data locally to cloud so it can be deployed to the internet?

I've just started my software dev journey, and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
